# How to hide Angular 9 background component for @media print while printing mat-dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

Here is my styles.css file, here `app-labour-value-estimate-print-layout` is a mat-dialog component which is over `app-material-details` component. When I try to print this mat-dialog, things from background pops out and so `app-root > * { display: none;}` this helped. However when added this code, any other components are not displayed in print as they as nested in `app-root`. How do I print root components as well as mat-dialog component without interference from background?

```
@media print {
  /*app-root > * {
    display: none;
  }*/
  app-footer  {
    display: none;
  }
  app-labour-value-estimate-print-layout {
    display: block;
  }
  app-material-details {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: try seeting width of mat dialog to 100vw and height to 100vh in media print?

Comment: Thanks, this worked upto some extent. I mean size increased but still there are some 1 inch margin from all sides and I never put up any such margins. Also scroll bar appeared. Any solution? Are there any way to put conditions in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside media-print

```
.cdk-overlay-pane {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}

mat-dialog-container {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked upto some extent. I mean size increased but still there are some 1 inch margin from all sides and I never put up any such margins. Also scroll bar appeared. Any solution? Are there any way to put conditions in css?

Comment: scroll bar will only come if your content is very big in modal,

Comment: This after adding display: block, it's height is restored to full screen. However width did not go as planned. Still 1 inch gap from both left and right ends, and also some portions of the dialog is cut from right end

Comment: @SubhrangshuAdhikary i believe you can customize css. But i have answered your question about how to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I additionally needed to update the function parameters which called the mat-dialog to adjust the width to 100vw. However I did't want that config in normal screen but only in print media. Tweaking quite a lot with different classes that didn't solve though but still it is working fine. Thanks a lot for your help.